# Azure Synapse notebook can read from SQL pool when run manually but task fails in pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I created a notebook with a simple command to read a table in from SQL Pool and display it:

```
%%spark
val df = spark.read.sqlanalytics("pool1.dbo.Trip")
display(df)
```

When I run this notebook manually, it works as expected. When I drag the notebook into an Azure Synapse single-step pipeline and manually trigger, the pipeline fails with error:

```
{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"InternalServerError executing request","target":"pipeline/Pipeline 1/runid/6938bd4c-35f4-414a-80d9-582dde84651c","details":null,"error":null}
```

The azure synapse service principal is listed as a user in the database I'm reading from and also has the db_owner role. I've also tried a "copy data" pipeline to/from the SQL pool, and that actually succeeded when triggered.

Did we potentially miss a configuration step when setting up the environment? Any ideas for troubleshooting this particular error?

Comment: did u ever figure out ?